# jQuery if element has class add class to 'this'

Tags: jquery, html, this

I am trying to make a menu where if a user hovers on 'menuItem' it will only show the submenu for that specific element.

I know you can use $(this) but in the jQuery when i change

```
$(subMenu).removeClass("hide-submenu").addClass("show-submenu");
```

to

```
$(this).removeClass("hide-submenu").addClass("show-submenu");
```

It doesnt seem to work

```
var menuItem = $("nav > ul > li > a");

var subMenu = $("ul > li > ul");


$(subMenu).addClass("hide-submenu");

$(menuItem).hover(function(){
if($(subMenu).hasClass("hide-submenu")) {
        $(subMenu).removeClass("hide-submenu").addClass("show-submenu");
}
else {
        $(subMenu).removeClass("show-submenu").addClass("hide-submenu");
}
});
```

Below is my HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>MENU ITEM</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">SUB ITEM 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SUB ITEM 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SUB ITEM 3</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try unchaining the methods

Comment: In you hover callback  this would be your `menuItem` not `subMenu`

Comment: You can use an jQuery toggle function, this will save you a few lines of coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code when you hover inside the `$(menuItem)` then when you use `this`, it refers to the `$(menuItem)` not to the `$(subMenu)`. Hence you can not use `this` here like you wanted to use it. Instead you can do this:

```
menuItem.hover(function () {

    // Go to the next sibling `ul` in the current scope, using `this`
    var $next = $(this).next('ul');  

    if ($next.hasClass("hide-submenu")) {
        $next.removeClass("hide-submenu").addClass("show-submenu");
    } else {
        $next.removeClass("show-submenu").addClass("hide-submenu");
    }
});
```

One more thing:

```
var menuItem = $("nav > ul > li > a");
```

`menuItem` is already a jQuery object here, you don't need to do `$(menuItem)` again. Same goes for the `subMenu`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `$(this)` contains `$(menuItem)` as Event is being called on `$(menuItem)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
var menuItem = $("nav ul li a");
var subMenu = $("ul li ul");
```

instead of

```
var menuItem = $("nav > ul > li > a");
var subMenu = $("ul > li > ul");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want

```
$("ul > li > ul").addClass("hide-submenu");

var menuItem = $("nav > ul > li");
menuItem.hover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').removeClass("hide-submenu").addClass("show-submenu");
}, function(){
    $(this).children('ul').removeClass("show-submenu").addClass("hide-submenu");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jt9fq/)